# How to generate fuzzy string similar to valid data to test input validation

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, unit-testing

This the format that I use to parse chess notation,
continue for black's move, and define variations.
`<1. Nf3 Nf6 2. e3 e6>`
`<1... Nf6 2. e3>`
`<main2 main 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. e3>`

I tested my parser with a bunch of test data.  Now, I want to test it with random fuzzy data that looks similar to the format.

How can I generate fuzzy test data that is 60% similar to valid format.
Like this:

`<1.` 
`<1. B3a`
`1<B N C>`

I tried this but it generates complete gibberish, kind of useless.

```
function genCode(len) {
  let chars = "<>abcdefgh.NBQRKO-12345678 ".split('');

  function nextChar() {
    return chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length)];
  };

  let res = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    res += nextChar();
  }

  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried this and it kind of works:

```
function repeat(code, n) {
  let res = "";
  while (--n) {
    res += code;
  }
  return res;
}


function corrupt(code) {
  let chars = "<>abcdefgh.NBQRKO-12345678 ".split('');

  function nextChar() {
    return chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*chars.length)];
  };

  let res = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    res += Math.random() < 0.8 ? code[i] : nextChar();
  }
  return res;
}

 console.log(corrupt(repeat(`<1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Ba5 Bg4 3. e4> <4... a6> <5... Qa7> <7... a8>`, 100\
)));
```